# Oracle TOAD in read-only mode

Tags: oracle, readonly, toad

I'd like to use TOAD in read-only mode to run queries on an Oracle DB in read-only.

I've read that you should copy the file *readonly.lic* over *toad.lic*.

What about the file *FullToad.lic*?

If anyone could tell me what is the difference between *toad.lic* and *FullToad.lic* it would be great (for example: should I copy readonly.lic to both toad.lic and FullToad.lic?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safest thing to do would be to create an Oracle User with query only privileges.

Comment: Paton: so this needs to done in Oracle and not in TOAD?  Sadly in my case it's easier to do this on the client side (i.e. in TOAD).

Comment: Ideally yes - because you at the mercy of the Quest developers to ensure they have made the app safe.

Comment: In regards to executing procedures, there's very little a client program like TOAD can do to guard against a procedure that does a commit (to end any concept of a read-only transaction), modifies data and commits those changes.